# HashAlgorithm.Create fails with PlatformNotSupportedException in C# ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an ASP.Net MVC project which works fine when using `HashAlgorithm`, but I am trying to replicate this same project in ASP.NET Core 2 and I am getting the following error:

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException HResult=0x80131539
> Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.
> Source=System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives
> StackTrace:
> at System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create(String hashName)
> at Hash.Program.EncodePassword(String pass, String salt)

My code:

```
public static string GeneratePassword(int saltlength) //length of salt
{
    const string chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var randNum = new Random();
    var passwordSalt = new char[saltlength];

    for (var i = 0; i <= saltlength - 1; i++) {
        passwordSalt[i] = chars[Convert.ToInt32((chars.Length) * randNum.NextDouble())];
    }
    return new string(passwordSalt);
}
public static string EncodePassword(string pass, string salt) //encrypt password
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] src = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt);
    byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length);
    HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("MD5");
    if (algorithm != null) {
        byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst);
        var encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
        return encodedPassword;
    }
    return pass;
}
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this error?

Comment: HashAlgorithm.Create is not supported on .NET Core, see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/wiki/ApiCompat#systemsecuritycryptographyhashalgorithmcreatestring. I guess you are expected to directly instantiate it, e.g. by using the [MD5 class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx). That being said you shouldn’t use MD5 in this day and age anymore as it’s insecure for several years now. Also don’t just hash you passwords, salt them and use a key derivation function like the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class.

Comment: If you know you're after MD5, why not use `MD5.Create()`?

Comment: DO NOT USE MD5 TO HASH PASSWORDS. EVER!

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out. This was a special case I only need a temp solution. This system is behind a secured firewall and on a intranet with one way traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an MD5 hash object, use `MD5.Create()`. The only reason to use CryptoConfig or `HashAlgorithm.Create(String)` is when handling dynamic needs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22626) for this problem which provides a workaround:

> Workaround is to call
>   `(HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(string)`, though calling
>   CryptoConfig directly is generally discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in other answers it's not a good idea to use MD5 as a hashing algorithm for passwords because it is too easy to crack. And while saying MD5 is insecure in general is not entirely correct, it is insecure for password hashing.

Basically a problem with simple hashing like that it is too cheap to run one iteration. That's why something named `Key Derivation Function` used for that purpose. The idea is that you need a CPU intensive algorithm (with multiple iterations) to do the hashing. While it's quite transparent for one user (let's say e.g. 100 milliseconds), it's too expensive to crack.

.Net has built in `Rfc2898DerivedBytes` for that. It's not the easiest class to use, so I have made a little library on top of this class: [SimpleHashing.Net](https://github.com/ilya-git/SimpleHashing.Net).

You can either use it directly or just use the code if you need .Net Standard. Did not have time to compile it as Standard yet.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be fixed in .NET Core 2.1:
[HashAlgorithm.Create throws PNSE on .NET Core 2 #22929](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/22929)

So upgrading to 2.1 (or newer) should fix the problem.

As the other answers shown, in general you should use `MD5.Create` (or actually better algos, like `SHA256.Create`). But in some cases, you might get the error, because other assembly that your project is using it calling `HashAlgorithm.Create`, so you cannot change that.